# Константы и глобальные переменные C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Вот в программе

```
const int a = 0;
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

a - является ли глобальной переменной?

Answer (score 3):

Она является глобальной константой в пределах модуля.

Comment: модуля? В C++ же нет модулей. Или имелся ввиду объектый файл?

Comment: Они тоже иногда модулями называются. Есно, не в том смысле, как в Питоне или Перле. Просто единица разделения текста и единица компиляции. А объектный файл - продукт их компиляции. Просто одним и тем же термином могут называться несколько разные вещи. Это типа полиморфизм.

Comment: @mikillskegg, и все таки я не понимаю - **почему в пределах модуля?**

Ведь если положить этот .o (с main) в lib1.so (`gcc -fPIC -shared -o lib1.so main.c`), написать функцию

    int get_extern_a() { extern int a; return a; }

и положить ее в lib2.so,

то третий модуль, загрузив  эти библиотеки и вызвав "get_extern_a" тоже (наряду с функциями в lib1.so и lib2.so) получит доступ к обсуждаемой переменной.

--

Так, что IMHO ее надо называть просто глобальной.

Comment: А напрямую ее получиться получить? Через вызов функции и значения автоматических переменных взять можно.

Comment: Зона видимости этой константы - все функции в данном модуле. В другом модуле непосредственно она не будет видима. И я не понимаю, что тут еще можно обсуждать.

Comment: Соглашусь с mikillskegg. Все из-за того, что настоящей модульности в Си нет. Кстати, интересно поведение С++ с учетом существования namespace и возможности их вложенности.

Comment: Не понял, то есть и static и const ограничивают видимость в пределах модуля? 

То есть чтобы переменная была точно глобальной для всех модулей, надо писать просто
int a = 0;

а в других модулях extern?

Comment: @mikillskegg, 

    А напрямую ее получиться получить? Через вызов функции ...

естественно, получится. Только при такой демонстрации все начнут спорить о ее "глобальности".

    В другом модуле непосредственно она не будет видима.

прекрасно видна через `extern int a;` Только модуль с ее определением (main.c) надо грузить с флагом RTLD_GLOBAL и перед модулями ссылоющимися (по extern) на нее.

Comment: @manking, да надо

        писать просто int a = 0; а в других модулях extern

Кстати, const **не ограничивает** область видимости, а не позволяет **изменять** значение переменной. Попросту этот адрес помещается в область констант, защищаемых (если ОС предоставляет такую возможность) от записи.

Comment: @avp, если рассматривать COFF, то extern сделает в этом модуле внешнюю ссылку на переменную `a`, причем на этапе сборки этого объектного файла, он даже знать не будет, где этот `a` находится, т.е. это будет означать, что `a` действительно существует в пределах модуля, во всех остальных это будет ссылка на глобальную переменную в заданный модуль. Так что технически, @mikillskegg скорее прав, по крайней мере в COFF.

Comment: Если у переменной или константы не указан модификатор extern/static, то она по умолчанию считается static (кстати, функции, в том числе методы классов, - наоборот). Если переменная определяется без extern, а в других модулях объявляется как extern, то при сборке линковщик будет сильно ругаться, что не может найти переменную.

Comment: @mega, это не свойство того или иного типа исполняемых файлов. Это стандарт языка. А в бинарном виде теоретически это может быть реализовано по-разному.

Comment: @mega, так будет не только в COFF, но и в других форматах объектного модуля. 

При такой логике, вообще, глобальная переменная может быть **только** в пределах модуля, а из других модулей, образующих программу (причем неважно, статически или динамически собранную) могут быть только ссылки на нее. Двух глобальных переменных с одинаковым именем в программе быть не может. 

IMHO все это настолько естественно, что уточнение "в пределах модуля" выглядит странно. 

--

Вот, захотелось бы увидеть какую-нибудь глобальную переменную *не в пределах модуля*.

Можете продемонстрировать?

Answer (score 1):

[[[[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg), к сожалению комментарии закончились. Наверное я не понял Ваш комментарий

```
Если у переменной или константы не указан модификатор extern/static, то она по умолчанию считается static (кстати, функции, в том числе методы классов, - наоборот). Если переменная определяется без extern, а в других модулях объявляется как extern, то при сборке линковщик будет сильно ругаться, что не может найти переменную.
```

Особенно в части ругани линковщика, но проверил.

```
// e1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ext = 999;

main ()
{
  printf ("main: int ext = %d\n",ext);
  ext++;
  e2();
  ext++;
  e3();
  printf ("End main: int ext = %d\n",ext);
  exit (0);
}

// e2.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int ext;

void
e2() 
{
  printf ("e2: extern int ext = %d\n",ext);
}

// e3.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int ext;

void
e3() 
{
  printf ("e3: extern int ext = %d\n",ext);
}
```

Вот оттранслировал и запустил

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc -c e1.c e2.c e3.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc -o e e1.o e2.o e3.o
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./e
main: int ext = 999
e2: extern int ext = 1000
e3: extern int ext = 1001
End main: int ext = 1001
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

Почему-то у меня никто не ругается...

**UPD** (спасибо, [[[[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg))

Вот что интересного увидел по поводу extern и const в C++.

Если написать в e1.c

```
extern  const int ext = 12999;
int const ext1 = 999;
```

и транслировать g++ -c e1.c  то в выводе nm e1.o увидим, что **`ext1` локальная константа** в секции .rdata, а **`ext` глобальная** в той же секции

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ nm e1.o
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 t .text
         U __Z2e2v
         U ___main
         U __alloca
         U _exit
00000000 R _ext
00000030 r _ext1
00000000 T _main
         U _printf
```

при такой записи (например в e2.c) (*отличается от ext в e1.c присваиванием*)

```
extern const int ext;
```

g++ -c e2.c делает такой .o модуль

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ nm e2.o
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 t .text
00000000 T __Z2e2v
         U _ext
         U _printf
```

т.е. **`ext`** здесь глобальная и не определена

Ну, теперь все линкуется, т.к. в модуле a1.o `ext` определена с флагом **R**, т.е. глобальная и определена.

Все же удивительное различие семантики слова `extern` для констант и переменных в С++.

Comment: ОК. А теперь ближе к вопросу: добавим const и запустим g++

Comment: Да, кресты с **`const`** не хотят (без const, кстати работает)

    c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ -c e1.c e2.c e3.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ -o e e1.o e2.o e3.o
e2.o:e2.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `ext'
e3.o:e3.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `ext'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc -o e e1.o e2.o e3.o
e2.o:e2.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `ext'
e3.o:e3.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `ext'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ 

Дурацкий язык

Comment: Все равно плюсую, потому что относительно переменных я был неправ

Comment: Можете сказать, модули в первую очередь предназначены для повышения скорости компиляции?

4 модуля скомпилировались...

изменяем модуль 3...

требуется компилировать только модуль 3,

Так как 1,2,4 уже скомпилированны.

Или есть еще какие моменты которые следует знать? Там есть какие нибудь шаблоны, которые изначально рассчитаны на модульное проектирование?

Comment: @mikillskegg, я тоже, как только узнал от Вас про такое с константами в плюсах.

Comment: @manking, видимо изначально модули возникли с целью повторного использования  кода. Побочным эффектом стало увеличение скорости сборки программ (особенно с появлением инструментов типа `make`). Наверное тогда же, параллельно с развитием структурного программирования, модули стали средством инкапсуляции, предшественником классов в ООП.

Однако, это мой взгляд (и мои воспоминания) на вещи. Может быть на самом все несколько иначе.

Comment: @avp Традиционно это называется "раздельная компиляция". И появилось очень давно (задолго до make и модулей типа modula-2 -- они вроде служат образцом модульности). Хотя уже после появился pascal (Виртовский), где раздельной компиляции не было, но это уже другая история -- язык-то создавался как чисто учебный.

Answer (score 0):

> [[[[@mega](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega), это не свойство того или иного типа исполняемых файлов. Это стандарт языка. А в бинарном виде теоретически это может быть реализовано по-разному.

[[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg), а я и не говорю о свойстве того или иного типа исполняемых файлов. Но здесь пишут об `extern`, выдавая его за свойство "глобальности" переменных, поэтому я уточнил его истинную функцию, касаемо COFF.

> [[[[@mega](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega), так будет не только в COFF, но и в других форматах объектного модуля. 
> При такой логике, вообще, глобальная переменная может быть только в пределах модуля, а из других модулей, образующих программу (причем неважно, статически или динамически собранную) могут быть только ссылки на нее.

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), что касается констант, Вы наверное и сами вкурсе, что большинство компиляторов сконфигурированных определенным образом, **глобальную константу физически даже заводить не будут** ни в одном модуле.

> Вот, захотелось бы увидеть какую-нибудь глобальную переменную не в пределах модуля.
> Можете продемонстрировать?

Наверное, Вы имели ввиду **глобальную переменную в пределах нескольких модулей**? Рискну предположить, что именно **технически** такой глобальной переменной будет та, что лежит в **`shared section`**. У Microsoft это может выглядеть как-нибудь так:

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/SECTION:.shared,RWS" )
#pragma data_seg( ".shared" )
int a = 0;
#pragma data_seg()
```

Здесь вся секция `shared` будет присутствовать в единственном экземпляре, независимо от того, сколько экземпляров программы запущено, т.е. `a` присутствует сразу в нескольких модулях, она глобальна и она "уникальна". Вы это хотели увидеть?

Comment: @mega, даже и не знаю. Такое впечатление, что весь этот разговор о глобальных переменных слишком усложнен.

Я смотрю на этот вопрос более приземленно. Если объект в выводе команды **`nm`** помечен "большой" буквой (флагом), то это глобальная переменная (или константа). В противном случае статическая локальная для данного объектного модуля. 

Область же ее видимости в исходном коде это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @avp суровый ответ сурового программера. Тэг vc++ имеет место быть? И где в ms vc++ команда nm?

Comment: А ms это истина в последней инстанции? В MinGW есть nm.